# what is the component with the circle mark?

Tags: infrared

I am trying to build an IR sensor module for line following robots, and I used QTRX-MD-06A module as my reference. The principle and PCB photos are attached here.

[image]  [image: Module PCB]

However, the component with a circle mark that is beside 47K resistor on the PCB is something I never saw before. I don't think it is a zero ohm resistor, because if it is, it means the light emitting diode will be directly connected to +5V and GND without any current limiting resistor. It would burn the diode, wouldn't it?

[image: Unknown principle]

Would anyone please let me know what it is? How does it relate to the current source symbol in the principle photo? Thanks in advance!

**[Answer]**

It turns out, there is a dedicated LED driver IC connected to the cathode of the light emitting LED. I guess this IC controls the LED current, and thus there is no need to use a current limiting resistor. So that component is indeed a zero ohm resistor. 
[image]

Comment: it is a zero ohm resistor

Comment: related: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417930/how-do-i-identify-this-component-it-just-says-0-on-it

Comment: Why don't you think it's a zero ohm resistor?  That's exactly what it looks like.

Comment: The reason I don't think it is a zero ohm resistor is that if it is a zero ohm, it means the light emitting diode will be directly connected to +5V and GND without any current limiting resistor. Wouldn't it burn the diode?

Comment: If you are dealing with electronics for robotics, you should have a DMM for sure. What kind if impedance does it show across the "o"-marked component ?

Comment: @Ale..chenski, I don't have the QTRX-MD-06A at hand. I only check the module introduction online.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your schematic, and the fact that you can tell the o and the 47k are in series by the zoomed in picture, I'd say it's a 0 ohm resistor.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out, there is a dedicated LED driver IC connected to the cathode of the light emitting LED. I guess this IC controls the LED current, and thus there is no need to use a current limiting resistor. So that component is indeed a zero ohm resistor. [image]